# How to adjust the .NET MAUI Picker windows size

Tags: maui, picker

Using .NET MAUI (7) Picker to display a selection of say 20 countries, I want to limit the size of the window (Android) used to display the selection. Currently, the selection windows expands when more options are added to the list until the selection windows covers the entire parent frame. I can't find a control that adjust the selection windows size. Appreciate any help/hints.

Went through the different MAUI Picker controls listed in the documentation (MAUI 7).
Tried to  include the picker in a frame/border/VerticalStacklayout with no result (as there should not be, as this will - as far as I understand - will only have effect on the Pickers display field - but desperation leads to crazy ideas :-)

Answer (score 0):

I created a Picker and try to Modify the selection windows size by Handler, but failed.

However, you can use [Popup of .NET MAUI Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup) to achieve your needs by customizing a picker.

Popup.xaml.cs:

```
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
               xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
               xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit" 
               x:Class="MauiApp3.SimplePopup">

    <VerticalStackLayout HeightRequest="200" 
                         WidthRequest="300">
        <ListView x:Name="listview" 
                  ItemTapped="listview_ItemTapped">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Button HorizontalOptions="End" Text="Cancel" 
                Clicked="OnCancelButtonClicked" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
    
</toolkit:Popup>
```

Popup.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class SimplePopup : Popup
{
    public ObservableCollection<NameId> NameIdList { get; set; }
    public SimplePopup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        createList();
        listview.ItemsSource = NameIdList;
    }
    private void
    OnCancelButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close("false");
    }
    void createList()
    {
        NameIdList = new ObservableCollection<NameId>
        { 
            new NameId { Id = "Id A", Name = "Name A" },
            new NameId { Id = "Id B", Name = "Name B" },
            new NameId { Id = "Id C", Name = "Name C" },
            new NameId { Id = "Id A", Name = "Name A" },
            new NameId { Id = "Id B", Name = "Name B" },
            new NameId { Id = "Id C", Name = "Name C" },
            new NameId { Id = "Id A", Name = "Name A" },
            new NameId { Id = "Id B", Name = "Name B" },
            new NameId { Id = "Id C", Name = "Name C" },
            new NameId { Id = "Id A", Name = "Name A" },
            new NameId { Id = "Id B", Name = "Name B" },
            new NameId { Id = "Id C", Name = "Name C" } 
        };

    }
    private void listview_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close((e.Item as NameId).Name);
    }
}
```

NameId.class:

```
namespace MauiApp3.Models
{
    public class NameId
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Page.xaml(it calls Popup):

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp3" 
             x:Class="MauiApp3.NewPage2">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="Select" x:Name="label">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Page.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class NewPage2 : ContentPage
{
    public NewPage2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var popup = new SimplePopup();
        var result = await this.ShowPopupAsync(popup);
        if (result.ToString() == "false")
        {
            return;
        }
        label.Text = result.ToString();
    }
}
```

It works well. About how to add Community Toolkit to your project, you can refer to this [doc by official](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/get-started?tabs=CommunityToolkitMaui).